# React native animated components affecting each other

Tags: react-native, react-animated

**Context:**

I have a component called `AnimatedSlider` and it is being used twice in `App.js`.

`AnimatedSlider` uses `React.Animated` to animate the width of a `View` within it. Here is the code.

`AnimatedSlider.js`

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Animated,
  Easing,
} from 'react-native';

const { Value } = Animated;

const MENU_ITEM_WIDTH = 50;
const MENU_ITEM_FINAL_WIDTH = 200;
const sliderWidthAnimatedValue = new Value(MENU_ITEM_WIDTH);

export default function AnimatedSlider() {
  const sliderState = useRef(-1);

  const animateExpantion = () => {
    Animated.timing(sliderWidthAnimatedValue, {
      toValue: MENU_ITEM_FINAL_WIDTH,
      duration: 250,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };

  const animateCollapse = () => {
    Animated.timing(sliderWidthAnimatedValue, {
      toValue: MENU_ITEM_WIDTH,
      duration: 250,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };

  const animateSlider = () => {
    if (sliderState.current === -1) {
      animateExpantion();
      sliderState.current = 1;
    } else {
      animateCollapse();
      sliderState.current = -1;
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Label</Text>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={animateSlider}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[styles.slidingMenu, { width: sliderWidthAnimatedValue }]}
        />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 50,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingLeft: 24,
    marginBottom: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
  },
  slidingMenu: {
    height: '100%',
    width: MENU_ITEM_WIDTH,
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
  },
});
```

`App.js`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

import AnimatedSlider from './components/AnimatedSlider';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <AnimatedSlider menuColor='pink'/>
        <AnimatedSlider menuColor='pink'/>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

**Problem: Clicking on one component, seems to animate the other as well.**

**You can check out the snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@griffintaimer/b8ccff)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the location of the following line.

```
const sliderWidthAnimatedValue = new Value(MENU_ITEM_WIDTH);
```

Moving it within the component resolved this problem. The reason being the instance of `Value` and thus `slideWidthAnimatedValue` was being shared between the instances of `AniatedSlider` component.